# See how many times the provisioned throughput was decreased within the same day in a DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there anyway to see how many times the provisioned throughput was decreased within the same day (UTC) in a DynamoDB table?

When increasing the provisioned throughput I am always afraid not to be able to decrease it afterward within the same day, since [one cannot decrease the provisioned throughput in a DynamoDB table more than 4 times within the same day (UTC)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html).

The monitoring graph's precision does not seem to be enough to see all previous provisioned throughput changes that happened during the same day. E.g. the provisioned throughput was decreased 4 times in this table, but one cannot see it on the graph:

[image]

[image]

And obviously Amazon does not give any warning in case we increase provisioned throughput while not being allowed to decrease it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of decreases is returned in a [DescribeTable](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTable.html) result as part of the [ProvisionedThroughputDescription](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ProvisionedThroughputDescription.html#DDB-Type-ProvisionedThroughputDescription-NumberOfDecreasesToday). It seems the DynamoDB console doesn't display this though and only shows the "Last Decrease Time".

Answer (score 0):

If this can help anyone, I wrote a Python function to see how many times the provisioned throughput was decreased within the same day for each DynamoDB table:

```
import boto
import operator

MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'copy your access key ID here'
MY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'copy your secret access key here'

def get_number_of_decreases_today():
    '''
    Scan all DynamoDB tables, and returns a dictionary with table name as key, NumberOfDecreasesToday as value.
    '''
    dynamodb_conn = boto.connect_dynamodb(aws_access_key_id=MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=MY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    table_names = dynamodb_conn.list_tables()
    table_number_of_decreases_today = {}
    for table_name in table_names:
        dynamodb_table_description = dynamodb_conn.describe_table(table_name)
        table_number_of_decreases_today[table_name] = dynamodb_table_description['Table']['ProvisionedThroughput']['NumberOfDecreasesToday']
        #print('NumberOfDecreasesToday is {0} for table {1}'.format(table_number_of_decreases_today[table_name], table_name))
    return table_number_of_decreases_today

def main():
    table_number_of_decreases_today = get_number_of_decreases_today()

    # Print table names and NumberOfDecreasesToday with alphabetically ordered table names
    for key, value in sorted(table_number_of_decreases_today.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
        print('{0}\t{1}'.format(key,value))    

    # Print table names by ascending NumberOfDecreasesToday
    for key, value in sorted(table_number_of_decreases_today.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (v,k)):
        print('{0}\t{1}'.format(key, value))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    #cProfile.run('main()') # if you want to do some profiling
```